# whole process at a single php file

Tags: php, performance, architecture

I'm doing the whole process at a single php file. For example; crud operation, writing forms,post/get data. Is that wrong? Or that causing performance loss?

Comment: You might be as well interested in http://php.net/phar

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not delimited or structured, it's hard to find some config to change it quickly. It maybe nice for you but hard for other developers who will support or fix your code in future.